# HighCharts : xAxis Categories Date format not working

Tags: ios, swift, highcharts

When I set Date format for `XAxis`. It's not working
Below is my code :

```
let options = HIOptions()

xAxis.type = "datetime"
xAxis.categories = ["2022-01-17T00:00:00","2022-01-18T00:00:00","2022-01-19T00:00:00","2022-01-20T00:00:00","2022-01-21T00:00:00"]

xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats = HIDateTimeLabelFormats() 

xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats.month = HIMonth()

xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats.month.main = "%e. %b"

options.xAxis = [xAxis]
```

It display original date from array only which I have set in `xAxis.categories`

Answer (score 0):

First of all I know this is not the best answer because this has nothing to do with `highcharts`. There should be a proper way of achieving this using `highcharts`.

Until someone post the correct way you can try this.

```
extension String {
    
    func formatStringDate() -> String{
        
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'hh':'mm':'ss"
        let date = dateFormatter.date(from: self)

        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour], from: date!)

        return "\(components.month ?? 0).\(components.day ?? 0)"
    }
}
```

use this as `xAxis.categories = ["2022-01-17T00:00:00","2022-01-18T00:00:00","2022-01-19T00:00:00","2022-01-20T00:00:00"].map{ $0.formatStringDate()}`

Answer (score 0):

Let's simplified your [example](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/se2wo430/), do  you want achieve something like this?

```
dateTimeLabelFormats: {
  minute: '%e. %b',
},
```

Maybe the format of your date is incorrect, have you tried giving values in milliseconds?

Comment: Yes i have try with milliseconds but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>

tooltip: {
            borderRadius: 5,
            useHTML: true,
            formatter: function () {
            var date = new Date(this.x);
            var formattedDate = moment(date).format('D MMM, YYYY');
            return formattedDate ;
          }
    },
```